# Split 2 separate data frames, apply functions simultaneously to both then combine

Tags: r, loops

I have 2 data frames:

df1 has a list of people who received vouchers at various weeks for a year. It shows which week each customer received their voucher.
df2 has daily transactions for the people in df1.

Each data frame has millions of rows

I would like to:
1- Split df1 by week, resulting in 52 data frames (df1.1, df1.2, df1.3.....df1.52)
2- for each of the 52 data frames I would like to do the following:

```
df2[df2$customer_ID %in% df1.1$customer_ID, ] %>%
   group_by(week_num) %>%
   summarise(tot_sales = sum(sales)
```

Each time the loop creates a data frame containing one row, i.e a single week.

So the resulting data frame (df3) will have 52 rows.

So far I have the following:

```
datalist <- list()

df1_split <- split(df1, df1$week_number)  

for (i in seq_along(df1_split)){
    
    for (j in df2$week_number){

   df2[df2$customer_ID %in% df1_split[[i]]$customer_ID, ] %>%
   mutate(week_received = j) %>%
   group_by(week_received) %>%
   summarise(tot_sales = sum(sales))

   datalist[[i]] <- dat
 
    {
 {

df3 <- bind_rows(datalist)
```

But this just runs continuously. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I meant to put j (mutate(week_received = j). Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: In your update, it is now extracting each column of `df1` with `i` instead of the `list` element from `df1_split`

Comment: I have now tried the solution, still running continuously.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is not able to be tested

Comment: Don't you actually want to `merge` or `join` on `week_num` instead of `%in%`? Right now, your logic returns `df2` customer that shows up anywhere in `df1` regardless of `week_num`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the nested `for` loop, subset the `df1_split[[i]]` instead of the original data

```
datalist <- list()

df1_split <- split(df1, df1$week_number)  

for (i in seq_along(df1_split)){

  for (j in df2$week_number){

      tmp <- df2[df2$customer_ID %in% df1_split[[i]]$customer_ID, ] %>%
        mutate(week_received = j) %>%
         group_by(week_received) %>%
         summarise(tot_sales = sum(sales))

         datalist <- c(datalist, list(dat))

    }
  }

 df3 <- bind_rows(datalist)
```